# Get color coordinates from image with different luminosity

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors

I have a challenge to get the color coordinates from the same image with different luminosity:
[image]
[image]

The goal is get the circle color coordinates and after that check if this this two images has the same color.
Can you give some ideias, how I can do this with python and openCV for instance? (Or other technologies)

Note: The image are the same (has circle with same color) but with only different luminosity.

Comment: introductory tutorial: color spaces, cvtColor, thresholding, inRange -- and if you want to normalize the image's brightness... there is some math for that. look up "white balance" and "gray world assumption" and apply that kind of math to luma instead of chroma

Comment: If you want to know if the colors are the same, you could check the Hue and Saturation and ignore the brightness value from HSV colorspace. Or get the color values of the A and B channels of LAB and ignore the lightness (L) channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normalize the luminance by multiplying the RGB components by `3 x 255 / (R + G + B)`.

Notice that the formula is singular for the black color, and you can add a small constant to the denominator to cope. Below, your two images so transformed.

[image]

[image]

This can be slightly better than getting the hue component alone, as you keep two degrees of freedom (saturation is preserved).